# Problem in merge sort. After running , it runs forever. I am not able to find out the mistake in the code

Tags: python, merge, mergesort

the code of my merge sort runs forever. I am not able to find out the mistake.
Have I missed the base condition to stop the code? If it is so still I am not able to find out the mistake.

```
def merge(arr, l, mid, r):
    n1=mid-l+1
    n2=r-mid

    leftarr=[None]*(n1)
    rightarr=[None]*(n2)

    for i in range(n1):
        leftarr[i]=arr[l+i]
    for j in range(n2):
        rightarr[j]=arr[mid+j+1]

    i=0
    j=0
    k=0
    while i<n1 and j<n2:
        if leftarr[i]< rightarr[j]:
            arr[k]=leftarr[i]
            i+=1
        elif rightarr[j] < leftarr[i]:
            arr[k]=rightarr[j]
            j+=1
        k+=1

    while i<n1:
        arr[k] = leftarr[i]
        i += 1
        k+=1
    while j<n2:
        arr[k]= rightarr[j]
        j+=1
        k+=1

def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if l<r:
        mid = (l+r)//2
        mergeSort(arr,l,mid)
        mergeSort(arr,mid+1,r)
        merge(arr,l,mid,r)

arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
n = len(arr)
print("Given array is")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i]),

mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1)
print("\n\nSorted array is")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i]),
```

In output I only get the input array and the sorted array is never printed.
The code runs infinitely.

[This is the image of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Nci.png)

Comment: Add some debug prints.  For example, `print(i,j,k,arr)` inside that first while loop.  What's happening is that loop is running forever, with `k` getting larger and larger, but even before you get there array is messed up.  You get [5,6,7,5,6,7].

Comment: get some small example, calculate every step on paper, and next add many `print()` in code to see if it gives the same value in all steps.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `k` should be initialized to `l` instead of `0`. As coded, the merge loop corrupts the beginning of the array.
- the test `elif rightarr[j] < leftarr[i]:` is useless and incorrect. `else:` suffices and the element from the right half will be copied. The test causes the loop to run forever if the next element from the left array and the right array are identical as neither `i` nor `j` are incremented. The array does not contain duplicate values, but the previous bug causes some numbers to be copied in the wrong place and hence may produce duplicates.

Note also that the initialization of `leftarr` and `rightarr` can be performed in a much more compact and efficient way: `leftarr = arr[l:mid+1]` and `rightarr = arr[mid+1:r+1]`

Here is a modified version:

```
def merge(arr, l, mid, r):
    leftarr = arr[l : mid+1]
    rightarr = arr[mid+1 : r+1]

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l
    while i < len(leftarr) and j < len(rightarr):
        if leftarr[i] <= rightarr[j]:
            arr[k] = leftarr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = rightarr[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

    while i < len(leftarr):
        arr[k] = leftarr[i]
        i += 1
        k += 1
    while j < len(rightarr):
        arr[k] = rightarr[j]
        j += 1
        k += 1

def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if l < r:
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        mergeSort(arr, l, mid)
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, r)
        merge(arr, l, mid, r)

arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
n = len(arr)
print("Given array is")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i])

mergeSort(arr, 0, n - 1)
print("\n\nSorted array is")
for i in range(n):
    print("%d" % arr[i])
```

Note these remarks:

- Using `r` as the index to the last element and `mid` the index to the last element of the left half causes many confusing `+1`/`-1` adjusments. A different convention is more idiomatic in Python, where `r` is the index beyond the end of the last element and `mid` the first element of the right half.
- `l` looks confusingly similar to `1`, which makes it a poor choice of variable name.
- saving the right half of the array slice is not necessary as its elements are copied before they may be overwritten.

Here is a simplified version:

```
def merge(arr, lo, mid, hi):
    leftarr = arr[lo : mid]

    i = 0
    j = mid
    k = lo
    while i < len(leftarr):
        if j >= hi or leftarr[i] <= arr[j]:
            arr[k] = leftarr[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            arr[k] = arr[j]
            j += 1
        k += 1

def mergeSort(arr, l, r):
    if r - l >= 2:
        mid = (l + r) // 2
        mergeSort(arr, l, mid)
        mergeSort(arr, mid, r)
        merge(arr, l, mid, r)

arr = [12, 11, 13, 5, 6, 7]
print("Given array is")
for v in arr:
    print("%d" % v)

mergeSort(arr, 0, len(arr))
print("\n\nSorted array is")
for v in arr:
    print("%d" % v)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter a bug, you should debug it manually or with a debugging tool, etc.

So, for your problem, we can insert a print function for debugging in the `mergeSort` function.
For example, print the `arr` when `l` equals 3 and `r` equals 4.

```
def mergeSort(arr, l, r):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
   if l<r:                                                                                                                                                                                                    
       mid = (l+r)//2                                                                                                                                                                                         
       mergeSort(arr,l,mid)                                                                                                                                                                                   
       mergeSort(arr,mid+1,r)                                                                                                                                                                                 
       merge(arr,l,mid,r)                                                                                                                                                                                     
   if l == 3 and r == 4:                                                                                                                                                                                      
       print(arr, l, r)                                                                                                                                                                                       
       exit()
```

Then the output is `[5, 6, 13, 5, 6, 7]`, which is not intended obviously.
Keep doing like so, print the `arr` in the middle of `mergeSort` function, you'll notice that you assign the array incorrectly in the 20th line.

In consequence, when the last merge happens (when `l` equals 0 and `r` equals 5), the `while` in the 18th line will loop infinitely, because the `leftarr[0]` equals `rightarr[0]`, which prevents `i` or `j` get increased.